# Precalculate value in pure functional javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming

I have code like this:

```
let createArray = (A) =>
  A.map((val) =>
    val * heavyFn(A.length)
  )
```

where `heavyFn(X)` is resources consuming function that returns always the same value for constant X. I believe good functional languages like Haskell optimize this, so `heavyFn(X)` is called only once for each result, but javascript obviously does not.

I could optimize it this way:

```
let createArray = (A) => {
  const H = heavyFn(A.length);
  return A.map((val) =>
    val * H
  )
}
```

But **is it possible to encode this in pure functional javascript?** I mean no variables, just parameters, no explicit return, no curly brackets, just nested arrow function expressions. Just out of curiosity if javascript has the functional abilities.

The only way I figured out was

```
let createArray = A => [heavyFn(A.length), ...A].map((val,i,H) =>
  val * H[0]
).slice(1)
```

but it seems like a hack.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a local binding. Unfortunately JS only supplies `let` as a declaration statement. Again you can mimic local bindings with the following combinator `const _let = f => f()`. Use it like `_let((x = 2; y = x * 2; z = y * 2) => x + y + z)`. As you can see `_let` uses default parameters and allows names to depend on previous declared ones.

Comment: I don't think that Haskell must optimize this (if so, it's an implementation detail of the optimizer). But know that there's nothing wrong with local bindings in pure functional programming. The term you are more likely looking for is _pointfree_, not pure. (And BTW, [pointfree.io](https://pointfree.io), given `\a -> map (\val -> val * length a) a`, spits out `map =<< (*) . length`).

Comment: @phipsgabler You are right. I figured lazy evaluation itself would lead to sharing, but even if I wrap both `heavyFn` and the lambda passed to `map` in an [implicit thunk](https://repl.it/repls/GroundedPuzzledRuntimeerror), `heavyFn` is still reinvoked at each iteration. So the function must be inlined with its body, which is totally reasonable but still a specific optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a curried function:

```js
const mult = x => y => x * y;
const createArray = A => A.map(mult(heavyFn(A.length)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over `heavy` with an IIFE.

```
let createArray = (A) => 
        (heavy => A.map((val) => val * heavy))
        (heavyFn(A.length));
```